# Replace grouped matches globally using Java RegEx

Tags: java, regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I have following PERL one liner. This perl RegEx simply upcase first letters of all the words of a given sentence.

```
$val =~ s/\b(.)(.*?)\b/uc($1).$2/eg;
```

Input:

```
"united states corp"
```

Output

```
"United States Corp"
```

However, I need to achieve same functionality in JAVA. I am doing following.

```
String INPUT="united states corp"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(.)(.*?)\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);
if (m.find()) {
    INPUT = m.replaceAll(m.group(1).toUpperCase() + m.group(2));
}
```

Input:

```
"United States Corp".
```

Output:

```
"UnitedUnitedUnitedUnitedUnited"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a regex like `\b\p{Ll}` to only match the first lowercase letter in words? Or do you plan to `.toLowerCase()` the rest of the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the first lowercase letter of words (in order not to match those that are already uppercase) you may use `\b\p{Ll}` regex and use `Matcher#appendReplacement()` method to manipulate the match:

```
String INPUT="united states corp";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\p{Ll}");
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, m.group().toUpperCase());
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString()); // => United States Corp
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/LVedpK).

As per [Java *Matcher* class docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> The [appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) and [appendTail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail(java.lang.StringBuffer)) methods can be used in tandem in order to collect the result into an existing string buffer

So, if you use your current regex, `"\\b(.)(.*?)\\b"`, you will need to replace the `while (m.find())` body with

```
m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(1).toUpperCase() + m.group(2));
```